# jQuery hasClass doesn't work for me?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In following code, `hasClass` doesn't work and result is `false` in alert. why, what do i do?

**Online Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Fe3CK/

HTML:

```
<span>
    <div class="adding"></div>
</span>
```

JS:

```
alert($('span').hasClass('adding'));
```

Comment: You shouldn't put a `<div>` inside a `<span>`.

Comment: you are checking the span for this class , but actually div has it ..so output false is correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you might be misunderstanding what [`.hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) does. It checks whether the element itself has one of these classes assigned. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

> Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.

If you want to check whether the element *contains* an element with that class, use [`.has`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.

```
alert($('span').has('.adding').length > 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need:

```
alert($('span div').hasClass('adding'));
```

since your `span` does not have any class `adding`. Only the child div of your span has it.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fe3CK/2/)**

Note: Only inline elements may be contained within inline elements. span is an inline element so block level elements like div or p cannot appear within a span.

Hence, `<div>` inside `<span>` tag is not a valid HTML5 markup so you should use `<div>` instead of `<span>` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to select div not span , as div has class of 'adding'

```
alert($('div').hasClass('adding'));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fe3CK/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check any children of span has class, then you can try like this;

```
alert($('span').children().hasClass('adding'));
```

Answer (score 0):

div inside a span is not a good practice and your span not have any class adding , adding is its child object's class so please use like

```
alert($('span').children().hasClass('adding'));
```